# Create JSON Object in While

Tags: php, json, while-loop

I need to create a JSON Object with PHP for Android API like this:

```
{"KEY":"VALUE","KEY":"VALUE"}
```

inside a while but i have tried with some code but nothing return this result.

```
$array = array();
    $array = array();
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
        $sped = $row[ 'codice' ];
        $stato = $row[ 'statosped' ];
        $array[] = array($sped => $stato);
    }
    echo json_encode( $array );
```

this return:

```
[{"KEY":"VALUE"},{"KEY":"VALUE"}]
```

Comment: Did you print $row to make sure you have the expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[array_merge](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php)**

`$array = array_merge($array, array($sped => $stato));`

Or

`$array[$sped] = $stato`

> Remembering that if there are two identical keys, the oldest one will be replaced by the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
    $sped = $row[ 'codice' ];
    $stato = $row[ 'statosped' ];
    $array[$sped] = $stato;
}
echo json_encode( $array );
```